# Trigger node command on the client side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping

I use this node based web scraper. https://github.com/lapwinglabs/x-ray

and I have to do `node test.js` in my thermal. How do I run that from client side? for example send ajax request from the client and do scraping.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an endpoint using express. For example, you can create something like this -

```
    var Xray = require('x-ray');
    var x = Xray();

    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();

    app.get('/webscrape', function(req, res) {
        var url = req.query.url;
        x(url, 'li.group', [{
                title: '.dribbble-img strong',
                image: '.dribbble-img [data-src]@data-src',
            }])
            .paginate('.next_page@href')
            .limit(3)
            .write('results.json')
        res.end();
    })
    
    app.listen(3000);
```

You just need to pass the url as a query parameter to -

```
http://localhost:3000/webscrape?url=https://dribbble.com
```

You can learn more about express routes [here](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)

If you want to run your `test.js` from browser, you can look at the excellent [Browserify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify) npm module.

Comment: I don't understand why I need browserfiy, I do understand the express in this usage.